# Interceptor invoked after bean validation

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, interceptor, bean-validation

I have the following RESTful web service:

```
@PermitAll
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Interceptors(AuthorizationInterceptor.class)
public JsonObject addUtente(@QueryParam("token") String token, 
                            @Valid UtenteDTO utenteDTO){
}
```

`AuthorizationInterceptor` contains a method annotated with `@AroundInvoke`. Bean validation on `UtenteDTO` object precedes interceptor invocation. It's a problem because token and roles verification is implemented in the interceptor and it must be the first control to be executed.

How can I invoke the method inside `AuthorizationInterceptor` before bean validation process?

Comment: Are you using CDI based interceptors? Have you tried `@Priority`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using CDI based interceptor. Isn't `@Priority` useful only in case a method has multiple interceptors?

Comment: I didn't find a solution with interceptors. I made AuthorizationInterceptor an implementation of `ContainerRequestFilter`. I annotated this class with @Provider and @Authorize (a custom interface). REST services which are annotated with @Authorize are subject to token and roles verification. This happens before bean validation invocation.

Comment: Validation is performed as an interceptor.  The fact that you're using `@Provider` though makes me think you think you're using CDI interceptors but you're actually using JAX-RS interceptors.

Comment: Now I'm using JAX-RS filters because they respect the priorities I'd like to have.